# How do I use LoadIcon and MAKEINTRESOURCE correctly when changing the title bar icon?

Tags: c++, winapi, codeblocks

I am working on a project in Code:Blocks c++ win32. I have read on this honorable page the use of LoadIcon and MAKEINTRESOURCE. However, it seems I am not using them correctly. I have created an icon with Greenfish and named it 'dvc icon'. It is in the format '.ico'.

When I execute the program I get an error code "can't open icon file 'dvc icon.ico': No such file or directory.

Below is the code.

```
#include <resource.h>

#define IDI_OWNERDRAW                   103
#define IDI_BUTTON_ICO                  201

#define IDI_dvc icon                    205


         /* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
wincl.hIcon   = LoadImage (GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_dvc icon));
wincl.hIconSm = LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_dvc icon), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, 0);
wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No me                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  u */
wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
```

What should I do next?
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use the WM_SETICON message.

Comment: You can use CreateDIBitmap function also

Comment: @DNamto: How does `CreateDIBitmap` help in creating an **icon**?

Comment: This is wrong, you should *never* create windows that are owned by the desktop. Pass `NULL` for that parameter, not `HWND_DESKTOP`. (Your comment is also syntactically wrong; you are not creating a child window (`WS_CHILD`), so it would not be a child of whatever window anyway.)

Comment: Yeah, you cannot use a PNG file as an icon. You *must* have an ICO file. Do a web search for an icon editor for Windows. [IcoFX](http://icofx.ro/) used to be the one I recommended, but it is no longer free. You might try [Greenfish](http://greenfishsoftware.blogspot.com/2012/07/greenfish-icon-editor-pro.html).

Comment: @Codey Gray Thanks for replying. I have used Greenfish and created an icon. However, I am not able use it in the application. I still get an error message. What should I do next?

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks a lot. The ICO files worked out. I was able to use the Greenfish app to create the icon. Well done. I so much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

There are the fields `hIcon` and `hIconSm` of type `HICON` in the [`WNDCLASSEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633576(v=vs.85).aspx) struct used by `RegisterClassEx`. It specifies what icon to use in the task bar and in the title bar of the window respectively. You can use `LoadImage` to get a valid icon handle. Use it together with the `MAKEINTRESOURCE` to get the icon from an embedded resource.

See the [LoadImage documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms648045(v=vs.85).aspx) for details.

Comment: You will actually need to use `WNDCLASSEX` here because you need the `hIconSm` field in order to get an icon in the title bar.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I fixed that and now refer to LoadImage instead of LoadIcon as well.

Comment: @kolrabi Thanks for replying...I have used LoadImage and MAKEINTRESOURCE but I do not know how to get the icon file I created from an  embedded resource. I used Greenfish in '.ico' format. What should I do next?

Comment: @kolrabi I have used LoadImage but I still get an error message " can't open icon file `dvc icon.ico': No such file or directory". What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Hmm... maybe it's not in the right folder. Try putting it in the same folder as the working directory of your .exe, which is usually (when using MSVC) the project folder, not the one with the .exe. Also make sure to set the correct parameters (set hinst to NULL, set the LR_LOADFROMFILE flag).

Comment: @kolrabi sure, I have to place the ico files in the same directory where bin folder is. Thanks a lot. It worked out perfectly.

Comment: @kolrabi I also added a resource header file and an .rc file. They were my embedded resources. Thanks. You really gave me a good hint as to what to do. You are amazing.

Comment: @lin Don't load it from a file, you don't want to introduce a dependency on that file. Sorry I haven't been following this comment exchange, so it sounds like you are using a resource file now. That's exactly the right solution.